# Redirecting to relative path using Laravel 4

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, laravel, reverse-proxy

Is it possible, in Laravel 4.1, to redirect to a relative path instead of the full path ? If we look at the `UrlGenerator::to` method, here what we have:

```
 public function to($path, $extra = array(), $secure = null)
    {
        if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) {
            return $path;
        }
        $scheme = $this->getScheme($secure);
        $tail = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', (array) $extra));
        $root = $this->getRootUrl($scheme);
        return $this->trimUrl($root, $path, $tail);
    }
```

This will act like this (meta-code):

mysite.com/url **Redirect::to('/test');** => mysite.com/test

What I'd want it's to be redirected to a relative URL:

mysite.com/url **Redirect::to('/test');** => /test

The problem it's that the company I'm working for, use a ReverseProxy to redirect all the traffic to HTTPS protocol, and with this kind of laravel redirects I keep getting redirected from HTTP to HTTPS :

- call: **GET** http:// mysite.com
- proxy: **GET** http**s**:// mysite.com
- redirect to login: **GET** http:// mysite.com / login
- proxy: **GET** http**s**:// mysite.com / login
- submit login: **POST** http:// mysite.com / login
- proxy: **POST** http**s**:// mysite.com / login

And the problem is that the submit form fail.

Is there a possibility to redirect to the relative path and let the proxy define the root url / protocol to use ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Laravel 4.2, I'm using `Redirect::away('/test')`, not sure if the function is there yet on Laravel 4.1.